# Get reaction time using angular - call a second function at second click event

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to make a little reaction time task in my ionic4 app. Basicaly, the page is white, when the user is ready he clicks the screen (screen changed color), then when the color will change again (after random time), I'd like to get the time.

html code :

```
<ion-content (click)="changeColor()" >

</ion-content>
```

.ts code

```
  changeColor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.theme.enableColor('light-theme');
      this.time1 =  new Date().getTime();
    }, this.randomTime);
    this.changeColor2();

  }

  changeColor2() {
    this.theme.enableColor('dark-theme');
  }
```

theme is my Service where I created enableColor which is simply a function which change the css attribute. This works correctly.

So when I click on the screen it works after a random time the color changed again and then when I clicked again I'd like the screen to change color again and find the time for which the user reacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make two variables startTime and endTime.
And [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) is probably a better solution.

```
startTime;
endTime;

changeColor() {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.theme.enableColor('light-theme');

  const self = this;
  this.endTime = performance.now();
  document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
    if (!event.target.matches('.scroll-content')) return;
    //event.preventDefault();
    // Log the clicked element in the console
    console.log('changeColor1');
    console.log(self.startTime - self.endTime);
    // because bubbling...
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }, false);
  }, 1000);
this.changeColor2();

}
```

The changeColor2() function

```
changeColor2() {
  this.startTime =  performance.now();
  this.theme.enableColor('dark-theme');
  console.log('changeColor2')
}
```

I have made a simple example on [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-reaction-time)

Comment: Thank you for your help! How can I allow only one "test", so it means 2 clicks, I will get a value of time and then the user could not try. Because if so, self.startTime - self.endTime is changing at every click... I tried to put all the code inside a if. If (counter === 1) then I run the code and at the end of the code I put a counter = 2, so normally you can not go inside the function. It works but the I got a time result of less than 0. @Beller

Comment: You should use a flag.